# Homotopy invariance in homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

i have this from Hatcher's book "Algebric topology"

[image]

And i don't understand why we have $i-1$ in $(-1)^{i-1}$ and strict inequality in $P\partial(\sigma)$ ?

Please.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the definition of $\partial$ and $P$ to compute $P\partial(\sigma)$?

Comment: $P\partial(\sigma)=P(\sum_{j=0}^p (-1)^j \sigma|[e_0,...,\widehat{e_j},...,e_n])$

Comment: and then what is it ?

Comment: The computation is not complete. $P$ is linear.

Comment: i dont understand @LeeMosher what do you mean by "the computation is not complete ?

Comment: @LeeMosher when $i<j$ i dont have problem , i have problen when $i>j$

Comment: As with many algebra problems, you must continue applying the laws of algebra, such as the linearity property of $P$, to simplify the expression as much as possible.

Comment: $P(ax+by)=aP(x)+bP(y)$. $P(\sum a_i x_i) = \sum a_i P(x_i)$.

Comment: this is the linearity of $P$, i know that $i$ goes from 0 to p-1 then why we have strict inequality and why $(-1)^{i-1}$ and not $(-1)^i$ please

Comment: I just saw you two were having a discussion as I was writing my answer. Hopefully my answers clears things up.

Comment: @LeeMosher can you help me i try to do an example to see how to compute $\partial P(\sigma)$ but i don't find $(-1)^i(-1){j+1}$ when $j\geq i$ see the last message http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16739/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-daniel-rust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that if $\Delta^n = [v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}, v_n]$ then for a map $\sigma\colon\Delta^n\to X$ we define the boundary operator $\partial\colon C_n(X)\to C_{n-1}(X)$ by
$$\partial(\sigma) = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{j} \sigma \mid [v_0,v_1, \ldots, \hat{v}_j,\ldots, v_{n-1},v_n]$$
and if, for an arbitrary chain $\alpha$, we have
$$P(\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i} F \circ (\alpha \times \mathbf{1}) \mid [v_0, \ldots, v_i, w_i, \ldots, w_n]$$ then $P\partial(\sigma)$ will be
$$P\left(\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{j} \sigma \mid [v_0,v_1, \ldots, \hat{v}_j,\ldots, v_{n-1},v_n]\right)$$ so we're taking the prism operator on an $(n-1)$-chain. When defining the prism operator we add in a $w_i$ next to $v_i$ as well as change the last $n-i$ vertices from $v_k$s to $w_k$s before restricting the function $F\circ(\sigma\times\mathbf{1})$ to this simplex. But remember if $k>j$ then $v_k$ is actually the $(k-1)$th vertex now because we no longer have $v_j$ in the order. If $k<j$ then $v_k$ is still the $k$th vertex as it's not shifted in its order. So we need to split these two cases up, and the shift accounts for the appearance of the $(-1)^{i-1}$ because odd and even vertex placements in the order have now swapped for all $i> j$. Also, $v_j$ does not appear in any chain for a fixed $j$ now because we've removed it, so the case $i=j$ in the sum doesn't make sense.

To make it a bit more clear, let's suppose that $n=5$, and we're looking at the term corresponding to $j=3$ with $i=1$. For ease of notation I'll ignore all of the function compositions and restrictions and just concentrate on the parity associated to the simplices. So, we start with the simplex $[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]$. The first thing we do is delete the vertex $v_j$ for $j=3$, and as $3$ is odd this means we have the modifier $-1$ associated to this simplex and we're left with $-[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5]$. Now, in the case $i=1$ we will add in a $w_1$ and replace all the $v_k$s with $w_k$s for $k>i=1$. Here $v_i$ is the $1$st vertex in the order* (because $i<j$) which is odd so we add another $-1$ modifier leaving us with $(-1)(-1)[v_0,v_1,w_1,w_2,w_4,w_5]=+[v_0,v_1,w_1,w_2,w_4,w_5]$.

What if we take an example were $i>j$. Let's try $n=5$, $j=3$ but with $i=4$ this time. We again start with $[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]$ which becomes $-[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5]$. Now, $i=4$ means we add a $w_4$ after $v_4$ and replace just $v_5$ with a $w_5$ this time. Also $v_4$ you will see is in the $3$rd place in the order now because we deleted $v_3$ which shifts everything on the right of $v_3$ one place to the left. So we associate another $-1$ modifier because $3$ is odd, giving $(-1)(-1)[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_4,w_4,w_5]=+[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_4,w_4,w_5]$.

Hopefully this highlights the necessity of splitting $i>j$ and $i<j$, and why $i=j$ doesn't actually make sense (because there's no $v_j$ to add a $w_j$ after).

---

*I'm concious of the fact that $1$st here doesn't actually mean there is nothing that comes before it, because the $0$th position holds that property... such is life when poorly defined English words are mixed with well defined mathematical notation.

Comment: who is k ?please

Comment: $k$ is just a variable as $i$ and $j$ were both fixed at various points.

Comment: i try for n=3, i start with $[v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3]$ it's become $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ for $i=1$ $v_1$ is in the first place then  we have $-[v_1,w_1,w_2,w_3]$ but this does not equal $(-1)^{i-1}(-1)^j [v_1,w_1,w_2,w_3]= [v_1,w_1,w_2,w_3]$ where is the problem ?

Comment: remember mathematicians start counting from $0$.

Comment: ah ok ok that's right thank you

Comment: i think you have done a mistake we must find +1 not -1 so $i=1$ the $(-1)^{1-1}(-1)^0=1$ and $1-1$ because v_1 becomes in the place of v_0 right ?

Comment: Sorry yes, because $i=1$, but $i>j$ the modifier is $(-1)^{i-1}(-1)^j$ which in this case is $(-1)^{1-1}(-1)^0=1$.

Comment: please i have an other question, when we calculate $\partial P(\sigma)$ for example for n=3, $P(\sigma)=[v_0,w_0,w_1,w_2,w_3]-[v_0,v_1,w_1,w_2,w_3]+[v_0,v_1,v_2,w_2,w_3]-[v_0 ,v_1,v_2,v_3,w_3]$ to compute $\partial P(\sigma)$ when $i=j$ we omitt $v_i$ and $w_i$ or only one of them ? thank you

Comment: Well note that $P(\sigma)$ is a $4$-chain so each boundary will have $5$ summands. Just use the definition of $\partial$ and I'm sure you'll be able to do some examples. Remember it's not the labels of the vertices that matter, or their indices, but just the order they appear in the simplex.

Comment: but when i=0 i have in the example [v_0,w_0,w_1,w_2,w_3] when i apllied $\partial$ what i must omit v_0 or w_0 ?

Comment: I think i have to omit $v_0$ but i dont find [v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3], how to do in this case j=4 but n=3 how to do please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16739/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-daniel-rust).

Comment: i stiil with my example, i hope that you can help me
i realised that $P(\sigma)\in C_{4}$ so when we past to the partial we must have j from 0 to 4
but for example when j=1 and i=0 i obtain $-[v_0,w_1,w_2,w_3]$ but in the book i must have $(-1)^i(-1)^{j+1}=(-1)^0(-1)^2=1$ not -1 where is the problem please