# Homotopy Invariance (Once again)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having a little trouble with the proof of Theorem 2.10 from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book. Here's a picture of the proof that I took from this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909005/homotopy-invariance-in-homology).

[image]

But my question is different. I'm having a really hard time seeing why $F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb{1}) \ | [\widehat{v_{0}}, w_{0}, \ldots, w_{n}]$ equals $g_{\#}(\sigma)$ and the same for $-f_{\#}(\sigma)$. It's clear to me that the $i=j=k$ will cancel with the $i=j=k-1$ in the second sum, but that's it for me.

Answer (score 1):

$F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb{1}) \mid [\widehat{v_{0}}, w_{0}, \ldots, w_{n}]$ is just $F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb{1}) \mid [ w_{0}, \ldots, w_{n}]$. One has the map $F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb{1}):\Delta_n\times I\to Y$. But $[w_0,\ldots,w_n]$ is just one of the ends ot the prism $\Delta_n\times I=\Delta_n\times [0,1]$, namely $\Delta_n\times\{1\}$.
So $F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb{1}) \mid [\widehat{v_{0}}, w_{0}, \ldots, w_{n}]$ is the composite
$$\Delta_n\stackrel{\sigma}\to\Delta_n\times\{1\}\to\Delta_n\times I\to X\times I\to Y$$
and so is the same as the composite
$$\Delta_n\stackrel{\sigma}\to X\to X\times\{1\}\to X\times I\to Y$$
and so to
$$\Delta_n\stackrel{\sigma}\to X\stackrel{g}\to Y$$
which is $g\circ\sigma$. Similarly for the other end of the prism.